# Implement Security In DDD (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, domain-driven-design

currently i'm working on an application using a domain driven design approach, one of my User modules is responsible for user management.

When it comes to authentication, authorization, I’m looking for the best way to implement security, where it’s supposed to be implemented in the domain or in another layer?

If you have any experience in DDD project please share with me your feedback .

I expect to have feedback on a security implementation using DDD as approach

Comment: Your security in terms of authorization and authentication should be part of Presentation layer.  So where interaction with external system happens.  Not sure what is the domain of the application but I don't think that your user management is part of the processes inside the domain.

Comment: _Secure by Design_ (Dan Bergh Johnsson et al) is something you should look into.

Comment: @J.Memisevic the user management is a part of m domain to manage creation and role attribution to user, regarding authentication and authorization is the part of code which suppose to identify user and provide access to restricted resource

Comment: @sayahimad in terms of design i think that identification of the users - that should be part of the presentation layer.  At least we do it like that(We use DDD). This is the question that I'm gonna try and follow - there are definitely more experienced people here than me.

Answer (score 0):

The objective of DDD is the representation of the business domain. If the functional specification indicates that a user must be authenticated before doing something, it must be represented in the domain. Certainly, authentication as such is a purely technical implementation, because it is necessary to load the user's data from a data source (persistence layer) taking into account the input data (presentation layer), but in your business layer (domain), you can have an entity representing the user and indicating whether he is authenticated or not. This entity is absolutely not the class used neither in the presentation layer nor in the persistence layer.

Structure of your classes:

### Presentation layer:

UserDTO

- username: string

### Domain layer:

User

- username: string
- authenticated: boolean
- roles (maybe...)
- some other business data...

### Persistence layer:

PersistedUser

- username: string
- pwd (!?)
- ...